# Continuous Linear Operator in $\mathbb{R}$- normed spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

> Let $E$ and $F$ $\mathbb{R}$-normed spaces and let $f:E\longrightarrow
>  F$ satisfying:
>
> 1. $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y) \,\forall x,y\in E$;
> 2. $f$ is bounded in the unit ball $B_E = \{x\in E: \Vert x\Vert \leq 1 \}$
>
> Prove that $f$ is a countinuous linear operator

I'm having problems to prove: $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R},\forall x\in E$, $f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$.

Assuming what is above, it is really easy to show that $f$ is continuous. Maybe I have to prove this assertion in $\mathbb{Q}$, but I couldn't prove it.

Comment: you want to show $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$

Comment: sorry for the typing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$
f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)=2f(0),
$$
we have $f(0)=0$. It follows that
$$
f(-x)=f(-x)+f(x)-f(x)=f(-x+x)-f(x)=f(0)-f(x)=-f(x) \quad \forall x\in E.
$$
Also for every $x\in E$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
f(2x)&=&f(x)+f(x)=2f(x)\\
f(3x)&=&f(2x)+f(x)=3f(x)\\
&\vdots&\\
f(nx)&=&nx \quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N}.
\end{eqnarray}
Since $f(0)=0$ and $f(-x)=-f(x)$, it follows that
$$\tag{1}
f(nx)=nf(x)\quad \forall x\in E, n\in \mathbb{Z}.
$$
Thanks to (1), for all $x\in E$ and all $n\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ we have
$$\tag{2}
f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)=\frac1n\cdot nf\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)=\frac1nf\left(n\cdot\frac{x}{n}\right)=\frac1nf(x)
$$
Combining (1) and (2), we have 
$$\tag{3}
f(rx)=f\left(\frac{p}{q}x\right)=pf\left(\frac{1}{q}x\right)=\frac{p}{q}f(x)=rf(x) \quad \forall x\in E, r=\frac{p}{q}\in \mathbb{Q}.
$$
Given $x \in E$, we denote by $\{q_n\}$ a convergent sequence of $\mathbb{Q}$ whose limit is $\|x\|$. Then for every $n$ we have
$$
\|f(x)\|=q_n\|f(x/q_n)\|\le q_n\sup_{z\in B_E}\|f(z)\|,
$$
and we deduce that
$$\tag{4}
\|f(x)\|\le \sup_{z\in B_E}\|f(z)\|\lim_nq_n=\sup_{z\in B_E}\|f(z)\|\|x\|.
$$
Thanks to (4) we have for every $x,y\in E$:
$$
\|f(x)-f(y)\|=\|f(x-y)\|\le \sup_{z\in B_E}\|f(z)\|\|x-y\|
$$
i.e. $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous.

If $r \in \mathbb{R}$, denote by $\{q_n\}$ a convergent sequence of $\mathbb{Q}$ whose limit is $r$. Then for every $x \in E$ we have
$$
f(rx)=f(\lim_nq_nx)=\lim_nf(q_nx)=\lim_nq_nf(x)=rf(x).
$$
Hence $f$ is linear.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is a remarkable solution.

Answer (score 2):

For example, note that $f(2x) = f(x + x) = f(x) + f(x) = 2 f(x)$, and hence $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} f(2x)$, which means $f(\frac{1}{2} x) = \frac{1}{2} f(x)$. Similarly one can prove that, for every $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, we have $f(qx) = q f(x)$. Now suppose $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Choose a sequence $q_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $q_n \rightarrow \lambda$. This implies that $q_n x \rightarrow \lambda x$. Now we have, since $f$ is continuous, $f(\lambda x) = \lim_{n} f(q_n x) = \lim_{n} q_n f(x) = \lambda f(x)$.

Comment: continuity of $f$ is also to be proved it is not given

Comment: OP stated that he has proved the continuity of $f$.